# File names of Parity keys

Tags: parity, keystore, parity-wallet

Why Parity keys are named differently?

I have one in the following format:

- `UTC--2016-11-21T14-59-51Z--109a31067644516b04549bddcb473e51fd0cf835`

And all the rest as:

- `UTC--2017-04-05T13-01-10Z--d4c80f9f-b59d-9c3e-d2ea-b20073690df8`
- `UTC--2017-04-05T13-00-53Z--49516ba7-ba23-1bae-bcb0-55f315e4a190`

My guess was that the unlocked account is renamed to include address, but it seems not to be the case either.

So how can I have all my key files named `UTC--2016-11-21T14-59-51Z--address`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parity imports your keys from Geth on first launch.

Geth addes the public key to the file name:

- `UTC--2016-11-21T14-59-51Z--109a31067644516b04549bddcb473e51fd0cf835`

For increased privacy, Parity keys do not include the public key in the file name. They use an [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) instead.

- `UTC--2017-04-05T13-01-10Z--d4c80f9f-b59d-9c3e-d2ea-b20073690df8`
- `UTC--2017-04-05T13-00-53Z--49516ba7-ba23-1bae-bcb0-55f315e4a190`

However, if you open the JSON, you will find the address inside. If you want to fully encrypt all meta-data of the file, you can create a [Vault](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Accounts%2C-Wallets%2C-Vaults#vaults).

> So how can I have all my key files named `UTC--2016-11-21T14-59-51Z--address`?

If you insist on having the public key in your file name, stop parity, and simply rename it. Parity will accept it.

*Disclosure, I work for Parity.*